# Python3 fuzzer get return code name

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, error-code

I've written a fuzzer to cause a buffer overflow on a vulnerable `C` application by creating a subprocess of it.

```
CASE #2 (Size = 24):
       IN: AjsdfFjSueFmVnJiSkOpOjHk 
       OUT: -11
```

`IN` symbolizes the value passed to `scanf`

`OUT` symbolizes the return value

the vulnerable program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 16 /* buffer size */

int main(void) {
  char name[N]; /* buffer */

  /* prompt user for name */
  printf("What's your name? ");
  scanf("%s", name);

  printf("Hi there, %s!\n", name); /* greet the user */

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

running this vulnerable program *manually* with my above generated payload it returns:

`Segmentation Fault`

Now to properly print the error cause I'd like to map the `int return value` to an enumeration -> like `Segmentation Fault = -11`

However, during my research I could not find any information on how these error codes are actually mapped, even for my example `-11 = Segmentation fault`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

> Popen.returncode
>
> The child return code, set by poll() and wait() (and indirectly by communicate()). A None value indicates that the process hasn’t
>   terminated yet.
>
> A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (Unix only).

-> [Unix Signals](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~alanjawi/cs449/code/shell/UnixSignals.htm)

Hope this helps someone else too.